# Inside ngOnChange, SimpleChange currentValue is defined but console log saids undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ngonchanges

Inside the typescript, there are a `name` variable takes input from another component.

```
@Input() name : any ;
```

And inside the ngOnChange I print the SimpleChange object like this.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChange){
    console.log(changes);
    console.log(changes.currentValue);
}
```

The result in the console is as followed.
[image]

I don't understand why in console, it can tells there are string `"Cafeteria Old Beach"` for `currentValue` property.
Yet when I `console.log(changes.currentValue)`, it returns undefined. How can I properly access the `currentValue` property value? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think you have to access like this. this.name.currentValue or changes.name.currentValue

Comment: For changes.name.currentValue , visual studio compiler throws error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'SimpleChange'.

Comment: For this.name.currentValue, The result is the same, Some how currentValue is still undefined.

Comment: I also tried the previousValue and the firstChange, all undefined.

Comment: once try changing SimpleChange to SimpleChanges and changes.name.currentValue will get your expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because after the changes there should be prop, in your case you have made `changes.currentValue`. and also change `SimpleChange` to `SimpleChanges` Please try following.

```
import { SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
export class TestComponent {
 @Input() name : any ;
 
constructor(){}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    console.log(changes);
    console.log(changes.name.currentValue);
    console.log(changes.name.previousValue);

}

}
```

Comment: It throws error ... error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'SimpleChange'. /  error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SimpleChanges'.

Comment: Yeah it works now , Turns out I haven't "update angular core" , with the help of visual studio code quick fix option , SimpleChanges works and its not undefined anymore .